# .onclick внешего блока вызывается во вложенном блоке. Bubbling

Tags: html, события, css, javascript

Есть всплывающий div, который вложен в затемнение у него сзади. При клике на затемнении div закрывается, но он закрывается и если кликать на него самого, и на элементы внутри него. Как сделать чтобы div закрывался только при нажатии на затемнение?

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="resdiv" style="display: none;">
        <a id="closebtn" href="javascript:;"></a>
        <p>Блок брони</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#resdiv {
width: 500px;
height: 550px;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin: -275px 0 0 -250px;
background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1);
border-radius: 2px;
font-size: 16px;
}

#overlay {
z-index: 100;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
function showdiv() {
gebiRd=document.getElementById('resdiv');
gebiOl=document.getElementById('overlay');
if (gebiRd.style.display=="none") {gebiRd.style.display="block", gebiOl.style.backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)", gebiOl.style.position="fixed"}
else gebiRd.style.display="none"
document.getElementById('closebtn').onclick = function() {
    gebiRd.style.display="none", gebiOl.style.backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", gebiOl.style.position="static"
}
gebiOl.onclick = function() {
    gebiRd.style.display="none", gebiOl.style.backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", gebiOl.style.position="static", stopPropagation()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверяйте, что элемент получивший событие является целью этого события:

```
gebiOl.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target !== this) return false; //ЗДЕСЬ!
    gebiRd.style.display = "none", gebiOl.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", gebiOl.style.position = "static", stopPropagation();
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/fZkNQ/

*в следующий раз делайте jsfiddle самостоятельно*